# how to access function caller context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand javascript scopes, and I want to know if in the following example:

```
// B can access 'context'
var a = function (context) {
    b = function () {
        console.log(context);
    };

    b();
};

a('nicccce'); // works!

// C can't access 'context'
var d = function () {
    console.log(context);
};

var c = function (context) {
    d();
};

c('oh oh'); // breaks
```

is there a way of accessing 'context' from the 'd' function?

**EDIT:**

I know I could pass the argument to the d function and thats obviously the **sane** thing to do, but I wanted to know if there was another way of doing it, maybe using `this.callee` as `this.callee.arguments[0]`.

Comment: Your examples illustrate the difference between [lexical and dynamic scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_and_dynamic_scoping). The latter doesn't exist in javascript.

Comment: @thg435 completely understood my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1) pass `context` into `d` as you do for `c` and `a`. or
2) put `context` int the lexical scope of `d`.

Option 2 sounds complicated, but it isn't.  That is exactly what you are doing in the case of `b`.  `context` is "closed-in" to the execution scope of `b` because the variable is available on the scope of the caller of `b` (because it is an argument to `a`).

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible and would result in very ugly/unreadable spaghetti code.

Why can't you pass it as an argument to the function? Another (but also ugly) solution would be declaring the variable in a scope where both functions can access it (i.e. in a parent function or global)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "context" is a variable scoped to function c() and a() (two different variables in two different scopes with the same name).

Judging from how you named the variable "context", I think [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is what you are looking for?

It is worth saying that scope in javaScript is actually very simple once you get block scope out of your mind. Anything appearing between `function { ... }` is a scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you pass context as an argument in c it will not break:

```
// C can access 'context'
var d = function () {
console.log(arguments[0]);
};

var c = function (context) {
d(context);
};

c('oh oh'); // doesn't break
```

And in d you will be able to access it by using argv/args (can't remember exactly) 
So something like args[0] or argv[0]

EDIT:

Changed code with arguments

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable that is in the top scope:

```
(function(){

    var global;

    var d = function () {
        console.log(global);
    };

    var a = function (local) {
        global = local;
        b = function () {
            console.log(global);
        };
        b();
    };

}())
```